# Setting foreign key name in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, foreign-keys, jpa-2.1

I am trying to set the foreign key name in Hibernate 4.3.10 on JPA 2.1 on Spring 4.1.6.

My entity is:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="generated")
@GenericGenerator(name="generated", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="identity"))
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, optional=false)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name="FOREIGN_KEY_NAME")) // attempt via JPA
@org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey(name = "FOREIGN_KEY_NAME") // attempt via a deprecated Hibernate annotation
private OtherEntity otherEntity;
```

What happends now is that I get a foreign key name like `FK_randomString` instead of `FOREIGN_KEY_NAME`.

How I can change the annotations to make Hibernate understand the